# TextView in ScrollView invisible

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a scrollview in my xml file and for some reason everything after tenAM and the second line is invisible inside of the preview. The linear layout that is inside the scrollview is taking up half the space even if I say `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` Here is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/header_layout" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llFooter"
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button android:id="@+id/datePick"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/confirmTime"
            android:onClick="timeSelect" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header" >

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView =android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/eightAM" />

            <View android:translationY="60dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/nineAM"
                android:translationY="60dp" />

            <View android:translationY="120dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/tenAM"
                android:translationY="120dp" />

            <View android:translationY="180dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/elevenAM"
                android:translationY="180dp" />

            <View android:translationY="240dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/twelvePM"
                android:translationY="240dp" />

            <View android:translationY="300dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/onePM"
                android:translationY="305dp" />

            <View android:translationY="360dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/twoPM"
                android:translationY="365dp" />

            <View android:translationY="420dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/threePM"
                android:translationY="425dp" />

            <View android:translationY="480dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/fourPM"
                android:translationY="485dp" />

            <View android:translationY="540dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/fivePM"
                android:translationY="548dp" />

            <View android:translationY="600dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/sixPM"
                android:translationY="608dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Why are my text and my lines not showing up?

Comment: Orientation in relative layout? Interesting

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using a `ScrollView` for the `TextView`s instead of a `ListView`?

Comment: This is meant for a calendar day view so I'm going to draw boxes indicating events either over the lines or behind the lines and I'm pretty sure I can't do that with a `ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set the **scrollview**'s *fillviewport property to true*. like this in xml `android:fillViewPort="true"` .

This is your xml use this:---

your xml:--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/header_layout" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llFooter"
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button android:id="@+id/datePick"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/confirmTime"
            android:onClick="timeSelect" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/header" >

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView =android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/eightAM" />

            <View android:translationY="60dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/nineAM"
                android:translationY="60dp" />

            <View android:translationY="120dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/tenAM"
                android:translationY="120dp" />

            <View android:translationY="180dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/elevenAM"
                android:translationY="180dp" />

            <View android:translationY="240dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/twelvePM"
                android:translationY="240dp" />

            <View android:translationY="300dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/onePM"
                android:translationY="305dp" />

            <View android:translationY="360dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/twoPM"
                android:translationY="365dp" />

            <View android:translationY="420dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/threePM"
                android:translationY="425dp" />

            <View android:translationY="480dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/fourPM"
                android:translationY="485dp" />

            <View android:translationY="540dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/fivePM"
                android:translationY="548dp" />

            <View android:translationY="600dip"
                android:translationX="60dp"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/sixPM"
                android:translationY="608dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Use this and enjoy...!